# Exam ques regarding iterators and generic functions

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm attempting to solve the below exam question but I'm having difficulties with it.

> Write a C++ function `find_elem` that takes two iterators first and last
>   of some sequence of elements of type `T` and an object `obj` of type `T`. It
>   returns the iterator to the first occurrence of `obj` in the range
>   (`first`, `last`), or the iterator last if `obj` is not in the sequence.
>   (35%)
>
> NOTE: `first` & `last` are not necessarily the same as what is returned by
>   a container’s `begin()` and `end()` methods! The only thing we suppose is
>   that the container is some sort of a sequence (e.g., vector, list,
>   etc.) and that first is an iterator which points to an element which
>   comes before the one pointed to by last. You must not dereference last
>   because it might be the result of `end()`!

Here's my attempt

```
template<typename Iter, typename Obj>
Iter find_element(Iter iter1, Iter iter2, Obj &obj){
 for(p = iter1; p != iter2; p++){
  if((*p) == obj){
   return p;
  }
 return iter2;
 }  
}
```

Is this attempt correct? Is the return type suitable for the function or have I got the wrong idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct. I would perhaps only change `Obj &obj` to `Obj const &obj`.

And you ought to have declared `p`.

More nitpicking: with generic iterators usually the form `++p` is preferred.

My variant (basically the same):

```
template<typename Iter, typename Obj>
Iter find_element(Iter iter1, Iter iter2, Obj const &obj)
{
    for(; iter1 != iter2; ++iter1)
    {
        if(*iter1 == obj)
            break;
    }
    return iter1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans, when the if condition breaks, would it automatically return the iterator at that point? I assume the iterator would be pointing at a specific obj when it returns?

Comment: @Sun: at `break`, the loop will be exited, and the line `return iter1;` will be executed. The value of `iter1` will be exactly what we need at that moment.